# How to use user input as history

Tags: bash, history

I am writing a script that takes a lot of user input, then creates a file from that input. Some of the inputs are fairly repetitive, and so I would like to enable the up arrow functionality to include the strings that have already been put in. I am having difficulty finding out how to do this.

I have tried

```
set -o history
```

but that only gives me the actual commands run, and not the inputs that have been received. I also know that

```
"\e[A"
```

is the up arrow command, but this is as far as I have gotten. A test script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o history

read -e date
read -e date2
read -e date3

echo $date $date2 $date3
```

After inputting `$date` I would like to be able to up arrow and get the contents of `$date` to use for `$date2`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to play with this little snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

HISTFILE=myhistoryfile
history -r
for i in {1..3}; do
   read -ep "Enter date $i: " d
   history -s "$d"
done
history -w
echo "Thanks for using this script. The history is:"
history
```

We define the file to be used as history file: `myhistoryfile` and load it into memory with `history -r`. Then we enter the loop and after each user input in variable `d` we perform

```
history -s "$d"
```

to append the input `d` to current history. At the end of the loop we perform

```
history -w
```

to actually write that to the history file.

Try different combinations: with/without `history -s` or `history -w` to understand what they really do. And [read the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Using-History-Interactively)!

Comment: This worked. I had that manual pulled up, but I didn't see the ```-s``` command.